# Tkinter GUI not showing output window

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
THEME_COLOR = "#375362"

class QuizInterface():
    def __int__(self):
        # super().__int__()
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title('Quizzler')
        self.window.config(pady=20,padx=20,bg=THEME_COLOR)

        self.score_label = Label(text="Score: 0",fg="white",bg=THEME_COLOR)
        self.score_label.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.canvas = Canvas(width=300,height=250,bg="white")
        self.question_text = self.canvas.create_text(text="Some Question Text",fill=THEME_COLOR)
        # self.question_text = self.canvas.create_text(150,125,text="Some Question Text", fill=THEME_COLOR)
        self.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)


        self.window.mainloop()
```

I have tried to search here and on YouTube for a solution, but I haven't found it.

Comment: that `def __int__(self)`. And later call to `super().__int__` should probably be `def __init__(self)` and `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 2):

You just created a class, but you didn't actually create an object using that class. You have to do something like

```py
quiz_interface = QuizInterface()
```

at the end, so that the `__init__` function is called.

Comment: Thanks. I did make that object in the main.py by importing the class and ran the program. However, the window still did not show up, there is no error message though so I am lost to what is wrong.

Comment: @CarlYamzon I just saw it, your `__init__` method has a typo, you wrote `__int__`

Comment: I wonder why it was not prompting it as an error

Comment: @CarlYamzon because you're allowed to use that as a function name.

Comment: Thanks again. I just double checked it has the int and init...gotta be careful next time